# Function within a function for iterating each rows based on a column value

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe

I currently am trying to create a function for a dataframe and is too complex for me. I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df1

     hour    production ....      
0     1          10
0     2          20
0     1          30
0     3          40
0     1          40
0     4          30
0     1          20
0     4          10
```

I am trying to create a function that would do the following:

1. Group data by different `hour`
2. Calculate 90% confidence interval of `production` for each `hour`
3. If `production` value of a particular row falls outside the 90% confidence interval for it's respective `hour`, mark it as `unusual` by creating  a new column

Below is the current step I am taking to do the above for each **individual** hours:

Calculate confidence interval

```
confidence = 0.90
data = df1['production ']
n = len(data)
m = mean(data)
std_err = sem(data)
h = std_err * t.ppf((1 + confidence) / 2, n - 1)
lower_interval = m - h
upper_interval = m + h
```

Then:

```
def confidence_interval(x):
if x['production'] > upper_interval  :
    return 1
if x['production'] < lower_interval :
    return 1
return 0

df1['unusual'] = df1.apply (lambda x: confidence_interval(x), axis=1)
```

I am doing this for each of the values in hour, than having to merge all the result together into one original dataframe.

Can anyone help me to crate a function that can do all the above at once? I had a go but just cant get my head around it.

Answer (score 2):

Create custom function and use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) and invert mask by `~`:

```
from scipy.stats import sem, t
from scipy import mean

def confidence_interval(data):
    confidence = 0.90
    n = len(data)
    m = mean(data)
    std_err = sem(data)
    h = std_err * t.ppf((1 + confidence) / 2, n - 1)
    lower_interval = m - h
    upper_interval = m + h
    #print (lower_interval ,upper_interval)
    return ~data.between(lower_interval, upper_interval, inclusive=False)

df1['new'] = df1.groupby('hour')['production'].transform(confidence_interval).astype(int)
print (df1)
   hour  production  new
0     1          10    0
0     2          20    1
0     1          30    0
0     3          40    1
0     1          40    0
0     4          30    0
0     1          20    0
0     4          10    0
```

Comment: `reset_index` may not needed if used `tranform` instead of `apply`.

Comment: @QuangHoang - Thank you.